# How to hide datagrid column in designer

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I don't know how to hide column in datagrid in designer. Could anyone help me? I know that I can do it from code, but is it possible without code behind?

I already try with TableStyles but it doesn't work.

Here is my datagrid configuration:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzSRe.png
and my BindingSource
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh8bG.png

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Marek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this in designer:**

- If you want to toggle between hiding a column and showing a column at
  design time, you only need to add the DataGridTableStyle once.
- To show the column, set the Width property of GridColumnsStyles to a
  nonzero value. for example:

  **DataGrid1.TableStyles("Products").GridColumnStyles("Quantity").Width
     = 100**